# Turn off "expect to receive" in RSpec

Tags: rspec, stubbing

I have an expectation in RSpec that is set in a `before` block:

```rb
context 'my_context' do
  before :each do
    expect(Net::HTTP).to receive(:new).at_least(:once)
  end

  it_behaves_like MyClient
end
```

However, I've just added a piece of code that means that `Net::HTTP` does *not* receive this message in one specific circumstance. (NB: the `shared_examples` block is already in place.)

```rb
shared_examples MyClient do
  it 'new code returns a 404 before creating a Net::HTTP' do
    # I want to remove the expectation here

    trigger_the_new_use_case
    expect(response).to be_not_found
  end

  it 'does other stuff'
end
```

I tried adding this line to override the expectation:

```rb
expect(Net::HTTP).not_to receive(:new)
```

... but it just adds *another* expectation; the original one is still there, and still fails.

I can't quite figure out how to use metadata to do it either, if that's possible. I tried to split the `before` block:

```rb
before :each do
  other_setup_stuff
end

before :each, wont_create_net_http: false do
  # I had hoped that `false` would act as a default value - I can't specify it in
  # hundreds of other tests - but it didn't. `nil` didn't either.
  expect(Net::HTTP).to receive(:new).at_least(:once)
end

before :each, wont_create_net_http: true do
  # This one worked OK
  expect(Net::HTTP).not_to receive(:new)
end

it 'new spec', :wont_create_net_http do
  run_the_spec
end
```

How can I remove, replace or disable the expectation for my new spec?

Comment: Have you considered using `allow` instead of `expect` in the `before` block? Typically, I only use expectations in `it` blocks.

Comment: That might be the more correct way to do it, but I'm working with legacy code here and don't want to change anything I don't have to.

Comment: Give it a shot. Should only take a couple of minutes to try. Might work!

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be done by using metadata to set a different expectation for this specific example, but you need to access the metadata in an `around` block and save it for later:

```rb
context 'my_context' do
  # Extract metadata
  around :each do |example|
    @example_wont_create_net_http = example.metadata[:wont_create_net_http]
    example.run
  end

  before :each do
    other_setup_stuff

    if @example_wont_create_net_http
      expect(Net::HTTP).not_to receive(:new)
    else
      expect(Net::HTTP).to receive(:new).at_least(:once)
    end
  end

  it_behaves_like MyClient
end

shared_examples MyClient do
  it 'new code returns a 404 before creating a Net::HTTP', :wont_create_net_http do
    trigger_the_new_use_case
    expect(response).to be_not_found
  end

  # other examples don't change
end
```